# node-red Mqtt, how to close socket connection

Tags: node.js, mqtt, node-red

red-contrib-mqtt-broker` as mqtt broker. connection/disconnection of clients, are happening fine but in backend sockets are not getting closed immediately so sockets getting pileup.and its leading to server down.

please help me how to resolve this issue.

here is my node-red flow

```
[
  {
    "checkall": "false",
    "id": "75e2813d.1200d",
    "name": "chkTopic",
    "outputs": 3,
    "property": "topic",
    "propertyType": "msg",
    "repair": false,
    "rules": [
      {
        "t": "eq",
        "v": "clientConnected",
        "vt": "str"
      },
      {
        "t": "eq",
        "v": "published",
        "vt": "str"
      },
      {
        "t": "eq",
        "v": "clientDisconnected",
        "vt": "str"
      }
    ],
    "type": "switch",
    "wires": [
      [
        "e44d3fd.601fcc"
      ],
      [
        "b0cbe2f0.fdf51"
      ],
      [
        "352b1527.c0382a"
      ]
    ],
    "x": 340,
    "y": 120,
    "z": "9207591e.000228"
  },
  {
    "dburl": "",
    "id": "169a1574.037e8b",
    "mqtt_port": "6883",
    "mqtt_ws_port": "6889",
    "name": "Silsung ST Connector",
    "password": "ajay1234",
    "type": "mosca in",
    "username": "admin",
    "wires": [
      [
        "75e2813d.1200d"
      ]
    ],
    "x": 140,
    "y": 120,
    "z": "9207591e.000228"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "complete": "payload",
    "console": false,
    "id": "b0cbe2f0.fdf51",
    "name": "",
    "tosidebar": true,
    "tostatus": false,
    "type": "debug",
    "wires": [],
    "x": 530,
    "y": 120,
    "z": "9207591e.000228"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "complete": "payload",
    "console": false,
    "id": "352b1527.c0382a",
    "name": "",
    "tosidebar": true,
    "tostatus": false,
    "type": "debug",
    "wires": [],
    "x": 530,
    "y": 180,
    "z": "9207591e.000228"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "complete": "payload",
    "console": false,
    "id": "e44d3fd.601fcc",
    "name": "",
    "tosidebar": true,
    "tostatus": false,
    "type": "debug",
    "wires": [],
    "x": 510,
    "y": 60,
    "z": "9207591e.000228"
  }
]
```

Comment: I assume you mean `node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker`. This node is meant for trivial testing, not high volume work loads. Use a proper separate broker e.g. mosquitto

Comment: yes, and I'm saying you should use mosquitto instead, because this node it not designed to be used for heavy workloads. Also MQTT is meant to have persistent network connections, not many connect/send/disconnect events so your model may be wrong as well.

Comment: Sorry and thank you, i will check. is it available for node-red? i checked it is not listing under **install** in manage palette

Comment: No, As I said in the first comment, it is a standalone separate process.